# Ternary operator vs if else

Tags: c

is ternary operator is better than if else block in execution time or under different scenerio? I have gone through many links but didnt get satisfied answer.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow!
Your question is too broad; as you already notice * under different scenerio* implies that there are many cases to consider. As you concern yourself with performance, you should already be aware of the fact that there are far too many factors to give you a general answer. There's nothing that can replace your own testing here!

Answer (score 7):

It isn't better or worse. It is *different*, because it is an expression. That means you can do stuff like initialize variables with it:

```
int n = some_flag ? 0 : 42;
```

or use it in other places that require expressions:

```
printf("Hello number %d", some_flag ? 0 : 42);
```

You can't do that with an if-else. As for performance, in cases where the two are interchangeable, it is extremely unlikely to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

On most of the modern compilers it makes no difference if you are using either of the two. The only thing you can concentrate upon is the maintainability of the code. The only difference you can get with ternary operator is that depending on some expression you can initialize a constant variable. Something like this:

```
const int a = (x<y) ? y : x;
```

which cant be done using if else